# How to merge multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, merge

I already know that if we have a list of two tuples like:

```
list = (('2', '23', '29', '26'), ('36', '0'))
```

by the below command:

```
new_list = list[0] + list[1]
```

it would be;

```
list = ('2', '23', '29', '26', '36', '0')
```

What shall I do if we have a plenty of tuples the below, and I want to use something like loop command?

```
list = [[list], [list2], [list3], ...]
```

I want:

```
new_list = [list1, list2, list3,...]
```

Comment: Those are not lists, they are tuples.

Comment: Search for "flat map" - it will yield results like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python (noting that real lists are used here)

Comment: Yes. Done. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), and you can simply supply the list as arguments using `*` to expand them.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a_list = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> list(chain(*a_list))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> tuple(chain(*a_list))
(1, 2, 3)
```

Also do not use pre-defined types such as `list` as a variable name as this redefines them to not being what they really are, and the parentheses `(1, 2...)` syntax results in a `tuple`, not a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> main_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9]]
>>> [item for sublist in main_list for item in sublist]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This uses a **nested list comprehension** approach. A good explanation of how to read them can be found [here](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2009/nested-comprehensions/).

Think how you'd do it with regular loops. One outer loop will extract a list and an inner loop will append every element of the list to the result.

```
>>> newlist = []
>>> for sublist in main_list:
        for item in sublist:
            newlist.append(item)

>>> newlist
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Similarly, in the nested list comprehension above - the `for sublist in main_list` extracts a sublist, the `for item in sublist` loops over each item and the `item` at the beginning of the comprehension does an automatic `list.append(item)` to the final result. The biggest difference from regular loops is that what you want to get automatically appended to the final result is placed at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are not merging two lists as you say in the question.
What you're doing is making a *list of list* into a *list*.

There are many ways you can do this. Apart from the ways listed in other answers, one possible solution could be:

```
for i in range(0, len(list_of_list)):
    item = list_of_list[i]
    for j in range(0,len(item)):
        new_list = new_list + [item]
```

Note: This solution is typically labelled as *C - like* as it doesn't make use of any Python methods.

Answer (score 0):

Using  [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) ,

```
>>> tp = ( ('2', '23', '29', '26'), ('36', '0'), ('4', '2') )
>>> newtp = sum(tp, () )
>>> newtp
('2', '23', '29', '26', '36', '0', '4', '2')
```

or  [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) ,

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> tp = ( ('2', '23', '29', '26'), ('36', '0'), ('4', '2') )
>>> newtp = tuple( chain(*tp) )
>>> newtp
('2', '23', '29', '26', '36', '0', '4', '2')
```

or comprehension,

```
>>> tp = ( ('2', '23', '29', '26'), ('36', '0'), ('4', '2') )
>>> newtp = tuple(i for subtp in tp for i in subtp)
>>> newtp
('2', '23', '29', '26', '36', '0', '4', '2')
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is using `reduce` inbuilt method.

```
>>> list_vals = (('2', '23', '29', '26'), ('36', '0'))
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list_vals)
('2', '23', '29', '26', '36', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, all the entries of the list are integers and so it would be easy to use `regular expressions`. The extra advantage of using regular expressions here is that it will work on any arbitrary nested list vs. chain that does not work when the list is `more than 1 degree nested`.

```
import re
alist = [[1], [2],[3]]
results = [int(i) for i in re.findall('\d+', (str(alist)))]
print(results)
```

The output is;

```
>>> [1,2,4]
```

So if we are given an `ugly` arbitrarily nested list like:

```
a_list = [[1], [2], [3], [1,2,3[2,4,4], [0]], [8,3]]
```

we can do;

```
a_list = [[1], [2], [3], [1,2,3, [2,4,4], [0]], [8,3]]
results = [int(i) for i in re.findall('\d+', (str(a_list)))]
print(results)
```

and the output is;

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 0, 8, 3]
```

Which is arguably more helpful.